# getting problem in point weighting in blender

Tags: rigging

I set strength to 1 in weight paint mode, but I am getting green and yellow colors also at the edges along with red color[image: Blender image].

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the "curve" parameter of the brush (in Photoshop is called "hardness").

In my example I've used 3 different curves, maybe you're looking for the second one (wich is the last preset on the right).

In the curve editor x axis is the distance from the center of the brush, y axis is the strenght of the stroke.

[image]

Comment: Thanks josh for your help, you are right i am looking for second one(only red color) but how to do that?I didn't get that.

Comment: You can click on the last of the 6 little buttons under the curve, or manually drag the points of the curve until you have an upper horizontal line (that means full action on the whole brush).